# Train test split based on a column values - sequentially

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, train-test-split

i have a data frame as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": ['A','B','B','A','B','B','A','B','A', 'A'],
                   "Col2" : [-2.21,-9.59,0.16,1.29,-31.92,-24.48,15.23,34.58,24.33,-3.32],
                   "Col3" : [-0.27,-0.57,0.072,-0.15,-0.21,-2.54,-1.06,1.94,1.83,0.72],
                   "y" : [-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1]})
    
       Col1 Col2    Col3    y
    0   A   -2.21   -0.270  -1
    1   B   -9.59   -0.570   1
    2   B    0.16    0.072  -1
    3   A    1.29   -0.150  -1
    4   B   -31.92  -0.210  -1
    5   B   -24.48  -2.540   1
    6   A    15.23  -1.060   1
    7   B    34.58   1.940   1
    8   A    24.33   1.830   1
    9   A   -3.32    0.720  -1
```

Is there a way to split the data frame(60:40 split) such that the first 60% of values **each group** of `Col1` will be train and last 40% test.

Train :

```
Col1 Col2    Col3    y
0   A   -2.21   -0.270  -1
1   B   -9.59   -0.570   1
2   B    0.16    0.072  -1
3   A    1.29   -0.150  -1
4   B   -31.92  -0.210  -1
6   A    15.23  -1.060   1
```

Test:

```
   Col1 Col2    Col3    y
5   B   -24.48  -2.540   1
7   B    34.58   1.940   1
8   A    24.33   1.830   1
9   A   -3.32    0.720  -1
```

Comment: Well, just use `loc`

Comment: SO you need each group in train and test follow 0.6 0.4  ?

Comment: Each group in col1  should follow 0.6,0.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel like you need `groupby` here

```
s=df.groupby('Col1').Col1.cumcount()#get the count for each group
s=s//(df.groupby('Col1').Col1.transform('count')*0.6).astype(int)# get the top 60% of each group 
Train=df.loc[s==0].copy()
Test=df.drop(Train.index)
Train
Out[118]: 
  Col1   Col2   Col3  y
0    A  -2.21 -0.270 -1
1    B  -9.59 -0.570  1
2    B   0.16  0.072 -1
3    A   1.29 -0.150 -1
4    B -31.92 -0.210 -1
6    A  15.23 -1.060  1
Test
Out[119]: 
  Col1   Col2  Col3  y
5    B -24.48 -2.54  1
7    B  34.58  1.94  1
8    A  24.33  1.83  1
9    A  -3.32  0.72 -1
```

Answer (score 5):

If need split without groups:

```
thresh = int(len(df) * 0.6)
train = df.iloc[:thresh]
test = df.iloc[thresh:]
print(train)
  Col1   Col2   Col3  y
0    A  -2.21 -0.270 -1
1    B  -9.59 -0.570  1
2    B   0.16  0.072 -1
3    A   1.29 -0.150 -1
4    B -31.92 -0.210 -1
5    B -24.48 -2.540  1

print(test)
  Col1   Col2  Col3  y
6    A  15.23 -1.06  1
7    B  34.58  1.94  1
8    A  24.33  1.83  1
9    A  -3.32  0.72 -1
```

EDIT: If need split per groups create treshold with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and filtering:

```
thresh = int(len(df) * 0.6 / df['Col1'].nunique())
print (thresh)
3

mask  = df.groupby('Col1')['Col1'].cumcount() < thresh 

train = df[mask]
test = df[~mask]
print(train)
  Col1   Col2   Col3  y
0    A  -2.21 -0.270 -1
1    B  -9.59 -0.570  1
2    B   0.16  0.072 -1
3    A   1.29 -0.150 -1
4    B -31.92 -0.210 -1
6    A  15.23 -1.060  1
print(test)
  Col1   Col2  Col3  y
5    B -24.48 -2.54  1
7    B  34.58  1.94  1
8    A  24.33  1.83  1
9    A  -3.32  0.72 -1
```

Comment: Right now I think we match the output :-) nice one

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use [`numpy.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
import numpy as np

train, test = np.split(df, [int(len(df) * 0.6)])

print(train)

  Col1   Col2   Col3  y
0    A  -2.21 -0.270 -1
1    B  -9.59 -0.570  1
2    B   0.16  0.072 -1
3    A   1.29 -0.150 -1
4    B -31.92 -0.210 -1
5    B -24.48 -2.540  1

print(test)

  Col1   Col2  Col3  y
6    A  15.23 -1.06  1
7    B  34.58  1.94  1
8    A  24.33  1.83  1
9    A  -3.32  0.72 -1
```